# Applying functions over multiple databases

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have the following list of large dataframes 
    `Cy3list<-c(AllCy3MeansDNA1bind1uM,AllCy3MeansDNA2bind1uM,AllCy3MeansDNA1bind10nM)`

Within these dataframes is a common column named molarity. I want to be able to change this column to numeric values then order them. I am using this function

```
'Cy3list<-c(AllCy3MeansDNA1bind1uM,AllCy3MeansDNA2bind1uM,AllCy3MeansDNA1bind10nM)
  lapply(Cy3list,function(x){
    x["Molarity"]<-as.numeric(x["Molarity"])
    x["Molarity"]<-order(x["Molarity"])
return(x)
  })'
```

I want to keep all the dataframes as they are, as in I want the function to loop over the dataframes and keep them as such, for ease of viewing as frames. When I run this loop the molarity is not ordered, it is ordered as:

> "10"      "100"     "25"      "5"       "50"      "10"      "100"
>   "25"      "5"       "50"      "10"       "100"     "25"      "5"
>   "50"      "10"      "100"     "25"      "5"       "50"    "Control"
>   "Control" "Control" "Control"

Notice that it is ordering by the first number not the whole number. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using this:

Construct your data:

```
AllCy3MeansDNA1bind1uM <- data.frame(Molarity=c("10" ,"100", "25", "5" ,"50", "10" ,"100",
                                                "25", "5", "50", "10", "100", "25", "5",
                                                "50", "10", "100", "25", "5", "50", "Control", "Control", "Control",
                                                "Control"), fake_col = rep(1,24) , stringsAsFactors=F)

AllCy3MeansDNA2bind1uM <- data.frame(Molarity=c("10" ,"100", "25", "5" ,"50", "10" ,"100",
                                                "25", "5", "50", "10", "100", "25", "5",
                                                "50", "10", "100", "25", "5", "50", "Control", "Control", "Control",
                                                "Control"), fake_col = rep(1,24), stringsAsFactors=F)


AllCy3MeansDNA1bind10nM <- data.frame(Molarity=c("10" ,"100", "25", "5" ,"50", "10" ,"100",
                                                "25", "5", "50", "10", "100", "25", "5",
                                                "50", "10", "100", "25", "5", "50", "Control", "Control", "Control",
                                                "Control"), fake_col = rep(1,24), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Store them in a list (note that I use the `list` function not `c`)

```
Cy3list<-list(AllCy3MeansDNA1bind1uM=AllCy3MeansDNA1bind1uM,AllCy3MeansDNA2bind1uM=AllCy3MeansDNA2bind1uM,
              AllCy3MeansDNA1bind10nM=AllCy3MeansDNA1bind10nM)
```

Then try this `function`:

```
library(gtools) #you need to load this library for mixedsort
new_df<-lapply(Cy3list,function(x) {
  x["Molarity"]<-mixedsort(x[["Molarity"]]) #notice the double brackets
  return(x)
})
```

I don't know if you need to have numeric data in your Molarity column (doesn't make sense when you have character data in there too). If you really need to then use this:

```
x["Molarity"]<- as.numeric(mixedsort(x[["Molarity"]]))
```

in the loop but notice that all your character data will be converted to NA and you ll get the corresponding warning too.

Validate that code works:

```
> new_df$AllCy3MeansDNA1bind1uM[['Molarity']]
 [1] "5"       "5"       "5"       "5"       "10"      "10"      "10"      "10"      "25"      "25"      "25"     
[12] "25"      "50"      "50"      "50"      "50"      "100"     "100"     "100"     "100"     "Control" "Control"
[23] "Control" "Control"
```

Columns are ordered!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Brilliant thank you! I have a few questions. Why do you use the '=' instead of ',' when creating the list

Comment: No problem. I 'm glad I helped. You need to have '=' to pass names to your list.